# Showing Recent Errors Only 4 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: swift, xcode

after I am search I don't have a solution of this problem
I am adding the admob to my xcode
this error occurs after I add the pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' and the pod install --repo-update on terminal

Please if anyone can help me this is the first time of using admob

[image]

Comment: What happens if you fix the yellow warning asking you to update to the recommended settings, clean you build and delete the Xcode Derived Data?